# Vue 3 - how to return html from function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use render functions with vue 3, and for some reasons i can't return my JSX directly in `return () => []`, but i need to return it from inside a function, and i was wondering if that's possible.

Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
const testreturn = () => {
    return h('div', { id: 'foo', innerHTML: 'hello world' }, [])
}

return () => [
    testreturn
]
```

If i try this, instead of seeing 'hello world' in my template, i will see the function `testreturn` printed out to the screen.

Instead if i try this:

```
return () => [
    h('div', { id: 'foo', innerHTML: 'hello world' }, [])
]
```

I will see a div in my template. Is there any way to accomplish what i'm trying to do in the first case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be enough to just call the function like that?

```js
return () => [
    testreturn()
]
```

This is in the end the same thing as when you include the `h(...)` directly in the return array. Vue won't execute a function when using it inside the template.

Comment: ... it was that easy. For some reason i tried that but the html wasn't being returned, maybe because of another error - tried again now and it worked.